# I want to return an Object, but I get a String

Tags: javascript, string, search, object, return

Hello I have a rather strange problem that doesn't make much sense.
I have a variable that's a string, and I want to search a property of an object(that's also an object) with the same name. Like so:

```
var ObjectProperty; /// multi-layer object
var PropertyName; //string
```

and if there's a match to the PropertyName in the Object, I want to return it.
Sample code:

```
OBJECT:
Bird.Raven = {
Name:"Raven",
Color:"Black",
} 
//Object

Bird.Duck = {
Name:"Duck",
Color: "Gray",
} 
//Object

Bird.Cardinal = {
Name:"Cardinal",
Color: "Red",
}//Object
///ObjectProperty sample.
```

Key I want to find inside "Bird":

```
var Cardinal = "Cardinal"; //string
///PropertyName sample.
```

Current Function I'm using, assume 'n' is the PropertyName variable I want to search:

```
var searchBirds = function(n) {
  for(var key in Bird) {
    var keyName = key.toString();
  if(keyName == n){
  console.log("bird " + key + " has been found.");
  console.log(typeof key);//RETURNS STRING
  return key;
  }
  else{
  console.log(n + " could not be found")
  };
  }
  }
```

Why is it returning a string when this should be an object? How can I make it return the key as an object? What's wrong? Vanilla Javascript preferred.

Thanks for the help, I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `for(var key in Bird)` iterates through the *names* of the enumerable properties on the `Bird` object. To get the *value* of that property, do `Bird[key]`.

Example:

```
var key, birdObject;
for (key in Bird) {
    birdObject = Bird[key];
    console.log(key + ".Color = " + birdObject.Color);
}
```

...would output

```
Raven.Color = Black
Duck.Color = Grey
Cardinal.Color = Red
```

...in [no specified order](http://farsightsoftware.com/misc/inorder.html) *(although nearly all engines will do them in the order the properties were added to the object [provided none of the property names is all digits, in which case there's more variation] — but that's **not** in the spec)*.

Comment: While I don't quite follow with the brackets and keys and properties(though I'm working on that) I have to say this works magic! Thanks!

Comment: @user2588440: :-) Object properties have *names*. There are two ways we can give the JavaScript engine the name of the property we want: Either by typing it as an "identifier," literally in the text, like the "height" in this: `a.height`, or by giving it to the engine as a string: `a["height"]`. The engine knows which of those we're doing because we use a `.` with the identifier, but we use `[...]` with the string. It's just two different ways of doing the same thing. And if we're using a string, it can be any string, so `a["he" + "ight"]` works, and `key1 = "height"` then `a[key1]` works.